# Twitter follow button username lost in chrome and safari

Tags: javascript, html, twitter

I'm having an issue with the twitter follow buttons in Chrome and Safari only. I have these 5 buttons in their own container so that I can fade them in to correspond with an animation that plays on the page. The buttons were showing up just fine before I added the script to fade them in. They should say something like Follow @twitterhandle. When I add the fadeIn script, the handle is removed from the button and it only says Follow. Below is the container with the 5 buttons:

```
<div id="bioTwitter">
    <a href="https://twitter.com/neverwakemusic" class="twitter-follow-button" data-show-count="false" data-lang="en">Follow @neverwakemusic</a>
    <br/>
    <a href="https://twitter.com/JohnnyD_NW" class="twitter-follow-button" data-show-count="false" data-lang="en">Follow @JohnnyD_NW</a>
    <br/>
    <a href="https://twitter.com/JB_NeverWake" class="twitter-follow-button" data-show-count="false" data-lang="en">Follow @JB_NeverWake</a>
    <br/>
    <a href="https://twitter.com/Geo_NeverWake" class="twitter-follow-button" data-show-count="false" data-lang="en">Follow @Geo_NeverWake</a>
    <br/>
    <a href="https://twitter.com/MG_NeverWake" class="twitter-follow-button" data-show-count="false" data-lang="en">Follow @MG_NeverWake</a>              
</div>
```

And here is the fade in script that is placed directly below the container:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#bioTwitter").hide(0).delay(1700).fadeIn(2000);
</script>
```

The buttons look normal in Firefox even with the fadeIn script. How can I make the twitter handles come back in Chrome and Safari?

Comment: Can you put together a fiddle/plunkr/codepen?

Comment: You can view the plunkr [here.](http://plnkr.co/edit/7V8oX5KxjA7nZTcPgRWS?p=preview) I didn't include any of my css but the problem is still visible.